# Copiar datos según criterios asociados a celdas con formulas

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Estoy tratando de copiar filas de datos contenidos en una hoja de cálculo especifica en Excel, estas con una condición particular, la cual es que copie las filas de datos en otra hoja de cálculo según sea que una de las celdas de estas filas de datos exactamente las ubicadas en la columna F no estén vacías, el inconveniente es que estas celdas están validadas por una formula y su valor varía respecto al resultado, es decir estas celdas están formuladas y el resultado de la fórmula es un valor definido o un dato vacío " ", estoy trabajando con la macro que muestro a continuación, el problemas es que me copia todos los valores, ya que interpreta los "datos vacíos" de resultado de la formula como una celda con valor. Quisiera si es posible me pudieran ayudar con la solución a esta situación que les presento.

```
Sub CopiarDatos()
    Set H1 = Sheets("VINCULACION_SV")
    Set H2 = Sheets("SEN_CONTENIDO_TABLERO")
    j = 3
    For i = 3 To 2600
        If H1.Cells(i, "F").Value <> "" Then
            H2.Cells(j, "D") = H1.Cells(i, "B")
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compañeros SO,

Lo pude solucionar con el siguiente código

```
Sub ConditionalCopy()
    Set H1 = Sheets("VINCULACION_SV")
    Set H2 = Sheets("SEN_CONTENIDO_TABLERO")
    j = H2.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    i = 3
     If H1.Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" Then
      H1.Range("B3").AutoFilter , Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"
      H1.Activate
      ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Select
      ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
      Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
      H2.Activate
      ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(j, "D"), Cells(j, "D")).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      j = j + 1
      H2.Activate
     End If
End Sub
```

Se los comparto, primero tuve que hacer un autofiltro con la condición, luego seleccionar la columna deseada con los datos filtrados y copiarla, después de esto hacer un pegado especial de solo valores en la hoja destino en la siguiente celda vacía de la fila seleccionada.